# what is counter part of empty_blob() of Oracle DB in HSQLDB?

Tags: blob, hsqldb

I am using a query in **oracle** in which I clean the blobs on regular intervals as:

```
Update table XYZ set ColumnABC= EMPTY_BLOB() where <<<<conditions>>>>
```

What to write in **HSQLDB** in place of **empty_blob()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty SQL binary string, `X''` can be used in place of an empty blob. You can write the EMPTY_BLOB() function using this string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION EMPTY_BLOB() RETURNS BLOB
    RETURN CAST(X'' AS BLOB);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fredt. You are always a savior. There is 1 more question, that I am using HSQLDB in standalone mode (with java app) and its size is 780MB (due to test data) right now due to BLOBS. Now I wanted to move it to Production envt. (without being involved in creating new fresh schema over there). Records are 5000 (with last record ID as 5000) in the table in which BLOBs are saved. I executed "Delete from Table_Name where ID>50".The records are deleted but size of the DB is still 780MB and the next record still creates with ID as 5001. Kindly tell me what to do in runManagerSwing editor?

Comment: You can execute PERFORM EXPORT SCRIPT DATABASE for a copy of the database see http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_data_management_statements

Comment: Please also note you should `accept` the good answers you get on stackoverflow.